# JQuery do not append on each iteration to avoid DOM redraws

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

i have this jquery code which probably causes DOM redraws at every step of the iteration. 
how can i do this only once?

```
$.each(d.sponsoren, function(k,v) {
        $("#sponsoren").parent().append( $("<div/>").append($("<a/>").attr("href", v.l).append($("<img/>").attr("src", v.im).css("margin","1").css("border","0"))) );
    });
```

Comment: It strongly depends on your content and how it will pressure your the painting engine. You can buffer all HTML content of the greatest parent and at the end dump it all into that parent again. It's probably the only way to be sure everything happens at the same time. Even buffering the jQuery commands and then for-looping those will probably still not be simultaneous. You will have to lock all other commands (clicks) that can trigger the drawing tho, otherwise you might mess up the drawing results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep the dom node in memory until the bucle has finished, then append node in memory to the DOM

```
var $tempnode = $('<div />');
$.each(d.sponsoren, function(k,v) {
        $tempnode.append( $("<div/>").append($("<a/>").attr("href", v.l).append($("<img/>").attr("src", v.im).css("margin","1").css("border","0")));
});
$("#sponsoren").parent().append( $tempnode );
```

Comment: Agreed. The same as what I mentioned in my comment :)

Comment: if you want to do a single append you need only one element, eitherways you will have multiple appends except you use the .html() function, but appending text is not as optimal as DOM manipulation, choose your way

Answer (score 0):

```
var markup = "";
$.each(d.sponsoren, function(k,v) {
    markup += "<div><a href='" + v.l + "'><img src='" + v.im + "' style='margin:1; border:0' /></a></div>";
});

$("#sponsoren").parent().append(markup);
```

Comment: This answer is almost identical to marcial's, except this buffers to a string, where marcial's buffers directly to the element.

Comment: just FYI DOM manipulation is way better than text append http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: As long as it's a raw string buildup it should be faster than doing anything with the DOM. Raw JavaScript will be faster than doing anything with the DOM in a loop. I can't confirm the impact on final append that is done on the DOM tho. But I can't imagine that is slower than touching a DOM element each time :) It's the same thing with doing `display: none;` on massive HTML-blocks. It can make painting really choppy, as the HTML really gets stripped off the drawn DOM canvas. We should be glad we are blessed with rocket-fueled JavaScript engines these days :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me was to start with a `Div` that has `display:none`, then append elements to that `div`, once done then set `display:block`. No redraw or blink effect now.

Answer (score -1):

Collect the elements in an array then append the array:

```
var elements = [];
$.each(d.sponsoren, function(k,v) {
         elements.push($("<div/>").append($("<a/>").attr("href", v.l).append($("<img/>").attr("src", v.im).css("margin","1").css("border","0")))));
    });
$("#sponsoren").parent().append(elements);
```

Comment: This is still very dependent on the size of the content. I've had issues with the OP case before. It's better to collect everything, because these DOM updates cause the painting engine to want to fully rerender the `document` DOM node's content, which in case of big content will look awfully choppy :)

Comment: @Allendar Could you explain further?  The `div` elements and their children are being created but not pushed to the DOM until the loop has finished.  Does simply creating the element trigger a `redraw` or `reflow`?

Comment: Not entirely. From a the native C-perspective; the slice-data you collect needs to be unpacked again by the parser, which takes exponentially more time than dumping the full HTML-string to the parser and letting it reparse it. With exponentially I still mean fractions of milliseconds tho. But in the case of big data it might cause stuttering. This story is practically the reason why Google forked Webkit to Blink. The problem is that JavaScript and the DOM are wrapped parallel from each other, which gives every operation from those to each other so-called byte-overhead.Causing sluggish behavior

Comment: Sorry I missed to comment on your last question; `reflow` is very dependent on which styles are applied. For example; absolute positioning will always cause `redraw`. As a lot of styles still cause `redraw` (Google for Paul Irish blog, it should show some comments from him on this matter), which is a bit of my default (shame on me :P) assumption for every modern day DOM manipulation action. I remember Paul's demo also showed a strong difference between transitions and transformations on the new CSS definition, where certain action strongly overload the drawing engine, causing hiccups.

Comment: append(elements) trigger the DOM events for each element (tested on Chrome), so that doesn't work.